# WCF Service can't return 1/1/0001 DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, datetime

I'm having an issue with a C# WebApplication that is calling a WCF WebService C#.
When I call the webservice with the method :

```
WebResponse myWebResponse = request.GetResponse();
```

I'm having an Exception thrown : "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"
The thing is that I also can debug the WebService Side so I know what is been returned as a Response and I noticed that i have this Exception only when there is a DateTime non initialized in the response of type : "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM".

Well you could just tell me to initialize my dates then, but the thing is this WebService is already in production working in its current state with those kind of dates. It also works like that for other developers that are debugging the project that are in the US (I'm in France(might be the problem ?))

The only thing different that I see between my working environment and the one from my colleagues in the US is the country...^^ 
We both use .NET Framework 4.5.1 and visual studio 2013 on WIndows seven SP1 and it's totally working for them, they told that they also have those dates non initialized(nothing surprising as we use the same source code) but they do get a response on the client side.

I have been searching all over the internet to try to find something similar but it seems that there is nothing like it, so if anyone has ever encounter this kind of trouble I please you to answer me :)

Thank you.

Comment: Being in France would make sense.  There was no December 31,1899 only December 30, 1899.  December 31, 1899 was a leap day.  So midnight Jan 1, 1900 EST would of been Dec 31, 1899 7:00 PM in France which never existed.

Comment: Why are you telling me about the date December 31, 1899 ?
It seems for me the date that is causing me problem would be:
January 1st 0001

Comment: Day zero in DateTime is midnight December 30 1899 and day 1 is Jan 1, 1900 skipping December 31. The DateTime constructor default is day 1 (not day 0) which is Jan 1.  The issue is if you subtract 5 hours from midnight Jan 1, 1900 do you get December 30, 1899 7:00PM or do you get December 31, 1899 7:00PM?  If you get December 31 then you have an error.  I'm assuming that in France you are calling the constructor for DateTime and then somehow the code is subtracting 5 hours the time difference between France and NYC.

Comment: Alright thank you for your explanation, so could i try to simulate my time as if I was in the US on my workstation ?

Comment: It really depends on the code.  You could set the PC timezone setting to a US timezone.  A PC stores a DateTime as a double in UTC starting at day 1 = 1/1/1900.  Each day equals one and the fraction being the fraction of the day.   The computer uses the TimeZone setting when inputting and outputting a string date to a DateTime object.  So to simulate a US computer all you need to do is to specify the Timezone when inputting or outputting a  string Date.

Comment: I tried to change my PC timezone this morning to US EST and it all worked  out instantly !
I really thank you for you answers jdweng, you have been really helpful !

Comment: DateTime string input to an application should include a timezone.  When data is collected in the same timezone as the computer settings there is no issue.  When data is collected in a different timezone than the computer settings either the string DateTime should have the timezone or the application should have an option to select the timezone.

Comment: Yes i agree with those recommendations but it's old code and i can't really have my hand on it. 
Now how do i select your answer as the good one ? I can't see the gray check mark next to it.

Comment: You can't since I only gave comments.  With answers you can move the arrows on the left side of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from jdweng :

Day zero in DateTime is midnight December 30 1899 and day 1 is Jan 1, 1900 skipping December 31. The DateTime constructor default is day 1 (not day 0) which is Jan 1. The issue is if you subtract 5 hours from midnight Jan 1, 1900 do you get December 30, 1899 7:00PM or do you get December 31, 1899 7:00PM? If you get December 31 then you have an error. I'm assuming that in France you are calling the constructor for DateTime and then somehow the code is subtracting 5 hours the time difference between France and NYC.